# Adding fling animation to my openmap application in flutter with snackbar message showing animation has started and ended

Tags: flutter, android-widget, flutter-animation, gesture, openmap

Wrapping the mapwidget inside gesture detector makes me lose properties such as rotating, scrolling, zooming. I want to add the fling animation.

Wrapping inside the gesture detector with onPanUpdate could not use the velocity property and thus cannot analyze if it is actually a fling. I want to be able to fling on the map and display a snackbar message with "Animation started" and "Animation ended".

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Maps Screen'),
        actions: [

        ],
      ),
      body: MapWidget(
        resourceOptions: ResourceOptions(
            accessToken:
            "my token"),
        mapOptions: MapOptions(
          pixelRatio: 1,
          crossSourceCollisions: false,
        ),
        cameraOptions: CameraOptions(
          center: Point(
            coordinates: Position(72, 30),
          ).toJson(),
          zoom: 21.0,
          padding: MbxEdgeInsets(top: 300, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 300),
        ),
        styleUri: MapboxStyles.SATELLITE_STREETS,
        onMapCreated: (mapboxMap) {
          _mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
          // User Location
          mapboxMap.location.updateSettings(LocationComponentSettings(
            enabled: true,
            pulsingEnabled: true,
            showAccuracyRing: true,
            puckBearingEnabled: true,
            puckBearingSource: PuckBearingSource.HEADING,
          ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```